# Which radio button is selected in a TRadioGroup?

Tags: delphi, integer, radio-button, lazarus, radio-group

As you can see in my question history, I'm developing a eBook manager, that will be open-source and I will release it in about 10 days, but I have a `TRadioGroup`, as you can see:
[TRadioGroup Used On My Form http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1830/radiogroup.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/1830/radiogroup.png)

And I want to store somethings in a variable(that needs to be a `Integer`) that will be "linked" with this `TRadioGroup`.

I need to do a `if` function like this:

> Caption Of The TRadioButton -> Number that will need to be stored in the variable
>
> Fit 2xWidth - Default -> 0
> Fit 2xHeight -> 1
> Fit Width -> 2
> Fit Height -> 3

But I just used a `TRadioGroup` and a `TRadioButton` one time, different than in C# that I've used more than 20 times. Then I want to know what I need to put on the if function, because what it will do I already know how to do:

```
var
  num: Integer;

begin
  if(TRadioButton1 checked?)
  begin
    num := 0;
  end;
end.
```

What I need to put inside the brackets of the `if` function?

PS: I'm going to put the credits on the program for the people that helped me in this little project.

Comment: From your question history, I thought you were writing a front-end for GCC. Why does an e-book manager need to invoke a C compiler?

Comment: It's a new feature of my eBook manager.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A TRadioButton has the Checked property. But A TRadioGroup has the ItemIndex property.

The items in a TRadioGroup are stored using a TStrings. So you can associate an object to each option and you can cast an integer to a TObject to be stored.

Example:

```
// fill the radiogroup
radiogroup.Items.AddObject('Fit 2xWidth', TObject(0));
radiogroup.Items.AddObject('Fit 2xHeight', TObject(1));
radiogroup.Items.AddObject('Fit Width', TObject(2));
radiogroup.Items.AddObject('Fit Height', TObject(3));
radiogroup.ItemIndex := 0;
```

To read the current setting:

```
value := radiogroup.ItemIndex;
```

Or to get the associated integer:

```
index := radiogroup.ItemIndex;
Assert(index>=0); // Sanity check
value := Integer(radiogroup.Items.Objects[index]);
```

In your case, the values are 0 to 3 so you can use the ItemIndex.

As a note, if is not a function. A function is a piece of code that returns a value based on the input parameters. If is a statement, which is a command that can be executed. The if statement is special because it enables you to execute a different statement based on the if condition.

Comment: Ok, but how can I use this piece of code to store they on a `Integer`, that will only held one number, that will be the one of the only one that is selected?

Comment: If Fit Width is selected, ItemIndex = 2, if Fix 2xWidth is selected ItemIndex = 0 etc..

Answer (score 6):

Just a little TIP: Setting `.ItemIndex` does not send keyboard focus to the radio item, i know how to fix it, read ahead.

Instead of selecting by code a Radio in a RadioGroup by setting `.ItemIndex` it is much better to do it by sending focus to the radio item; just to be very clear: i mean sending focus just to the radio item, not the whole radio group.

Instead of: `radiogroup.itemindex:=TheIndex;`

Do it as this: `TRadioButton(radiogroup.Controls[TheIndex]).SetFocus;`

It will make the radio item to be selected and **send the keyboard focus to it**, so it will display the dotted rectangle arroud it, just as if the user had clicked on it.

Note1: To see it in action use keyboard cursor keys and compare behavor of just setting `.ItemIndex` and sending focus to radio item.

Note2: If you use `TRadioButton(radiogroup.Controls[TheIndex]).SetFocus;` then there is no  no need to set `.ItemIndex` at all, it will also be done.

Hope that helps someone having the same problem as me, when need to set it by code, for example to avoid circular keyboard behavor, for example for making it to stay on last radio item when last radio item is selected and keyboard right cursor is pressed, same for first.

Comment: Excellent observation!

Comment: This nifty bit of logic solved a wacky problem we had with a form getting stuck in a loop based on the OnClick event. Thanks!